Why did my ram decrease after reinstalling ubuntu?
Before it said i had 7.7 GIB of ram. after i reinstalled ubuntu it now says i have 7.17 GIB Of ram in htop, free -h, anything that reports the amount of memory you have
and no. im not confusing gibibytes with gigabytes

This question is similar to: Why is GiB used insteed of GB. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

7.7 GB = 7.17 GiB  so you're likely confusing the actual value.   There are many tools in GNU/Linux from difference sources following different standards; so its very common for different tools to use different standards & thus present the same data differently.  It's been argued how to deal available RAM in OSes since the late 1960s, as if RAM is available for malloc() requests it is available, but if it's currently used as cache the same area of RAM is both available & used.. how tools treat this varies (*this is example only).

This question is similar to: Why do free and lshw show different RAM sizes?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

im not confusing the value, it decreased. free -h --giga said 8.2gb before the reinstall. now it says 7.7gb, and free -h used to say 7.7G but now it says 7.17G.

https://pastebin.com/YFS9a320
